# Calling a Webservice from a C# Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I have created a class library - MyNS.MyClass. The Library has a Service Reference to a Webservice (added through Add Service Reference) - the Service Reference shows up as MyNS.VS in the Project. The class library is MyNS.dll. MyClass has a static method myStaticFunc which calls the Web Service

I have a separate C# console application where I add reference to this DLL. I have code there calling MyNS.MyClass.myStaticFunc. My project compiles fine. But when I run it, I get an exception

> {"Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
>   'VS.MyObj' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This
>   might be because no configuration file was found for your application,
>   or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found
>   in the client element."}

To get rid of this exception, I have to also add a Service Reference in my Console Application & give it the same name (VS - however, here the namespace would obviously be my client app's namespace).

I don't understand why this needs to be done - it's the Library which is calling the WebService - the app is not calling it directly - and the Library does have the Service Reference. And why does the workaround work - in spite of the namespaces being different?

Comment: Please have a look on below links :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352654/could-not-find-default-endpoint-element http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583220/could-not-find-default-endpoint-element-that-references-contract

Comment: You should specify the endpoint in the .config file of your main app.

Comment: @Anand_Systematix - the linked question does not describe why this needs to be done

Comment: The answers above are correct. You need to have endpoint configuration in your app.config file. Visual studio will add it automatically when you add a service reference to a project. That's why your workaround works. Open app.config in your library project and copy the settings to your app.config in your console app and it will work without adding a reference.